# how to pass result from MySql query to ejs in node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, arrays

I am creating a dashboard that displays a number of data in different charts (e.g. horizontal bars, pie charts etc.)

I am using node js as a backend, MySQL as database, and ejs to render the data to html page.

I have had MySQL queries ready to query different data. The problem that I am having when I need to encapsulate these MySQL queries inside the routing function and pass the results to ejs.

Here is the sample code

```
router.get('/participant-module',(req,res)=>{

let sql1 = dbModel.participant_per_module; // MySQL query string
let sql2 = dbModel.error_per_module;  // MySQL query string
let count_emp = [];
let count_error = [];

db.query(sql1, (err, result)=>{
    if(err) throw err; 
    count_emp.push(result);

});

db.query(sql2, (err, result)=>{
    if(err) throw err;
    error_count.push(result);
  
});

res.render('dashboard', {emp_count:count_emp, error_count:count_error}); // pass array to ejs
});
```

count_emp and count_error are display in different charts. But, here the count_emp and count_error are always null.

I have tried to search for similar problem in the forum and the cause seems to be db.query is async so it won't wait and thus when res.render send the data, emp_count and error_count are still null.

So does anyone have a workaround on this?

Thank you in advance

D

Answer (score 0):

Your `db.query` calls and `res.render` are running asynchronously without waiting for the query result. What is happening is that, your first query is fired, then immediately your second query is fired, then immediately your router is returning the response. You are not waiting for the queries to retrieve the results. That's why your `count_emp` and `count_error` is `[]` every time the response is rendered.

Try this:

```
router.get('/participant-module',(req,res)=>{

let sql1 = dbModel.participant_per_module; // MySQL query string
let sql2 = dbModel.error_per_module;  // MySQL query string
let count_emp = [];
let count_error = [];

db.query(sql1, (err, result)=>{
    if(err) throw err; 
    count_emp.push(result);

    db.query(sql2, (err, result)=>{
      if(err) throw err;
      error_count.push(result);
      res.render('dashboard', {emp_count:count_emp, error_count:count_error}); // pass array to ejs
  
    });


});

});
```

PS: You should try to avoid over-nesting of callbacks. It is commonly referred as callback hell. Some common ways are: 1. Using promises 2. Using named functions